# Java final string parameter is not marked as compile time error in lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, functional-interface

Consider the following code:

```
public class Test {
  interface Changeable {
    void change(String s);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test t = new Test();
    Changeable c = (s) -> s = s + " World"; // Line 1
    final String str = "Hello";
    t.changeIt(str, c);  // Line 2
    t.changeIt(str, (s) -> s = s + " Hello");  // Line 3
    System.out.println(str);
  }

  public void changeIt(String s, Changeable c) {
    c.change(s);
  }
}
```

How is a final variable `str` in this case, able to satisfy the above lambda. Perhaps I'm interpreting the code wrong but it **looks** like the lambda expression is re-assigning the `str` variable. Running the code (and seeing that it compiles) obviously contradicts this, what am I missing?

Comment: The lambda expression is reassigning its own local variable `s`.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand, is `s` not referring to `str`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression is equivalent to:

```
Changeable c = new Changeable() {
  void change(String s) {
    s = s + "World";
  }
}
```

But s is the local reference to the string, so reassigning s you are not changing the original str reference, just the local one.

Comment: Thanks for writing this succinctly and clearly. Think context switching between c++ and java lead to the confusion. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See this for example:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String str = "Hello";
    changeIt(str);
}

public static void changeIt(String s){
    s = s + "World";
}
```

The brackets in Java describe your scope. The String `str` as such only exists in the scope of your `main`-Method. If you pass it along and re-assign it, that won't affect `str`, and as such it won't interfere with `final`.